# which windows driver kit should i install for OS Windows10 and visual studio 13?

Tags: visual-studio, twincat

I have Microsoft visual studio 13 in System which has Operating System Windows 10. Which windows driver kit shall I install to add c/c++ diver in program?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads#download-iconimagesdownload-installpng-wdk-81-update-for-windows-81-8-and-7-drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You install the driver-kit that is suggested in the Manual for C/C++-extension in TwinCAT:
http://download.beckhoff.com/download/document/automation/twincat3/TC1300_C_EN.pdf.

Read chapter "Installation "Microsoft Windows Driver Kit 7 (WDK)".
Even though it specifically says it's for Windows 7, it's working for Windows 10 as well. Note that this is only required on your engineering machine, you don't need to install this on the PLC.